# HOME environment variable (or HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH) must be set (character issue?)

Tags: ruby, jekyll

Trying to run Jekyll and getting the following error:

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rbreadline.rb:1097:in `<module
:RbReadline>': HOME environment variable (or HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH) must be set
 and point to a directory (RuntimeError)
```

However, things seem to be fine:

```
C:\>set home
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\Náme
```

Could it be the accent in my home path? If so, how can I fix it?

Running Ruby 2.2.6 and jekyll 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it's helpful to someone: it turns out that the accent was indeed the culprit. I had to rename the user folder (which was a pain) using these instructions: https://superuser.com/questions/495290/how-to-rename-user-folder-in-windows-8